# Is type of variables can help in linearization?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I was wondering if the type of variables, whether binary or non-negative can affect the linearization?

For example assuming that $x_{i,j,t}$ and $y_{i,t,s}$ are two binary variables, then when we want to linearize $ \sum_{i,j} x_{i,j,t} \ge 1 \implies \sum_{i} y_{i,t,s} \ge 1 \quad \forall t,s$ then could we say?
because they are both binary: this is equivalent to  $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j,t} \le \sum_{i} y_{i,t,s} \quad \forall t,s$?

(note that the $i$ in the left and right should not necessary be the same, I just want having for one $i$ , $y_{i,s,t}=1$)

Or we have to use indicators like $\delta =1 \implies \sum_{i,j} x_{i,j,t} \ge 1 $ and then $ \delta=1 \implies \sum_{i} y_{i,t,s} \ge 1$

I knew that if $x,y$ were not binary, we should use indicator trick, but it is necessary here??

Comment: $ \sum_{i,j} x_{i,j,t} \ge 1 \implies \sum_{i} y_{i,t,s} \ge 1 \, \forall t,s$ is *not* equivalent to $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j,t} \le \sum_{i} y_{i,t,s} \, \forall t,s$ (unless there are other constraints that limit both sums). Suppose that $ \sum_{i,j} x_{i,j,t} = 2$ but $\sum_{i} y_{i,t,s} = 1.$ The original implication constraint is satisfied but the new constraint is violated.

Comment: @prubin Prof, but $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j,t} \le M\sum_{i} y_{i,t,s} \quad \forall t,s$ will make sense?

Comment: @Sutanu Yes, and a suitable value for $M$ is the number of $(i,j,t)$ triplets for any $t$ (so not necessarily the same $M$ for each $t$). Other parts of the model might make it possible to find tighter values of $M.$